# Какой тип переменной больше чем TStringList?

Tags: delphi

Запихиваю определённый текст(очень много символов) в переменную типа TStringList, но вылетает ошибка мол не хватает памяти. Какой тип переменной мне лучше выбрать?

Comment: Обычный TStrings вас не устраивает?

Comment: м, абстрактный класс предлагаем:)

Comment: @KoVadim, с одной стороны вы правы, но с другой стороны можно дописать, всего пару функций (`getCount`) и у вас полностью рабочий класс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Быть может, у вас ошибка Access Violation, исключение(Exception) типа EAccessViolation, которая является самой распространенной при работе с таким типом. Если это так, то у вас не "памяти не хватает"(  ведь объект класса TStringList расширяется при необходимости, а более гигабайта( думаю, у вас гораздо больше ОЗУ =) ) он вряд ли будет занимать, только если вы не каждую звезду во вселенной перечисляете =) ), а вы пытаетесь обратиться к НЕДОСТУПНОЙ области памяти.